# c# cant't get property from entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm giving support to an application so I don't understand in deep how things were made. But I'll try to explain my problem so with your help I may solve the problem or make a better question.
Here I go:
I'm getting an object and when I'm debugging I see  2 properties with the same name (Id) I want to get the value from the one that is different than cero. Using entity.Id is returning cero value. And (in this example) I want to return the one with 118 value

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing you have an `Id` property on the subclass that is _hiding_ the `Id` property of the base class. Look at your compiler warnings.

Comment: It seems that the `Id` property has been hidden (maybe with the `new` keyword) by another property of the same name in your `Client` entity. Remove the redundant property from that class.

Comment: I'm guess that you are declaring Id property into child class instead of having parent class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue**

Your issue is most likely because the `new` operator has been used to redeclare a property which is already in the base class. As shown below:

```
public class A
{
    public int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public new int Id //<-- new is used
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Then if we have a generic method with a constraint like this:

```
public static void Do<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : A
{
    Console.WriteLine("entity Id is: {0}", entity.Id);
}
```

we are only able to use things from type `A` and not `B`. Since we never assigned `1` to `A.Id`, it still has the value `0`. To prove that, we can call the above method like this:

```
var b = new B();
b.Id = 1;
Do(b);
```

and it will write this to the console:

> entity id is: 0

However, if you did this and forced the compiler to choose `B.Id` then `Id` will have `1`:

```
Console.WriteLine("entity Id is: {0}", (entity as B).Id);
```

**Solution**

The solution will be tricky.

1st option is to use the `as` operator as I have done above, but then your method will no longer be generic.

The 2nd option is to figure out why the `new` operator was used to hide the base member; maybe the reason is good but most likely it was because: The base class was handwritten and the inheriting class was generated by EF and since they both had `Id`, compilation was failing. Then the developer created a partial class and did a hack by redeclaring the `Id` property in the class with the `new` operator. If there is no good reason, do not inherit the base class but then you will not be able to use the generic method.

The 3rd option is to remove the `Id` property from the base class but then that will also break a lot of code.

As you see, the issue is architectural: it is a poor design.

**Temporary Fix**

As a temporary fix, create yourself a task so you do not forget to discuss this with your team members. For now just do this:

```
// HACK: @Devs: I had to do this as a temp fix but we need to discuss why I did this
//       and discuss the possible fixes.
B b = entity as B;
if (b != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("entity Id is: {0}", b.Id);
}
```